# Find asymptotic upper and lower bounds for $T(n)=T(n-2)+ 1/\lg n$

Tags: asymptotics, recurrence-relations

I am trying to find the $\Theta$ of $T(n)=T(n-2)+ 1/\lg n$. Assume that T (n) is constant for sufficiently small n. I know this comes down to find the $$\sum_{k=1}^{\frac{n}{2}}\frac{1}{\lg(2k)}$$. But I got stuck. I would appreciate any hints. 
A follow up question is what is the $\Theta$ of $T(n)=aT(n-b)+f(n)$, where $f(n)$ can be any common functions i.e. $n!,3^n,n^3,n\log n, \log n$, or any combination of those. Does master theorem apply?

Comment: Hi, as a forum of help you're please to describe what you've already tried, even if it is not relevant to your eyes.

Comment: I recognize this has to do with solving the $$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\lg k}$$. However, I cannot find any log identities to simplify it further.

Comment: Look at this https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LogarithmicIntegral.html. By using double inequalities on your sequences you could reach it.

Comment: Have you tried yo apply master theorem ?

Comment: I don't think master theorem apply...

Answer (score 0):

Its $\Theta(\frac{n}{lg\,n})$

Lower limit is easy to see $$\sum_{k=1}^{\frac{n}{2}}\frac{1}{lg(2k)} \geq \sum_{k=1}^{\frac{n}{2}}\frac{1}{lg(n)} = \frac{n}{2\cdot lg(n)}$$

Upper limit is a little harder as we usually try to break things in $[n, n/2], [n/2, n/4] \dots$ intervals, but that wouldn't work here. Instead break it into just two intervals $[n, \sqrt n]$ and $[\sqrt n, 1]$ $$\sum_{k=1}^{\frac{n}{2}}\frac{1}{lg(2k)} = \sum_{k=\left\lfloor \frac{\sqrt n}{2}\right\rfloor + 1}^{\frac{n}{2}}\frac{1}{lg(2k)} + \sum_{k=1}^{\left\lfloor \frac{\sqrt n}{2}\right\rfloor}\frac{1}{lg(2k)} \leq \sum_{k=\left\lfloor \frac{\sqrt n}{2}\right\rfloor + 1}^{\frac{n}{2}}\frac{1}{lg(\sqrt n)} + \sum_{k=1}^{\left\lfloor \frac{\sqrt n}{2}\right\rfloor}1 = \frac{n}{lg(n)} - \frac{2\cdot \left\lfloor \frac{\sqrt n}{2}\right\rfloor}{lg(n)} + \left\lfloor \frac{\sqrt n}{2}\right\rfloor$$